# radio button onclick return false remove the checked from the other radio button

Tags: javascript, jquery, radio-button

I have radio button. I want that `onClick` on the radio button It will return false. What that happend is that the radio that i change is not checked and it is good . but the other radio button that was checked before. is not checked too.
here the code:

```js
function disableClick(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  return false;
}
```

```html
<input id="fmale" type="radio" name="gender" value="1" checked="checked" onclick="return disableClick(event);">
<input id="male" type="radio" name="gender" value="2" onclick="return disableClick(event);">
```

Comment: Why? why you want to return false and prevent default, what is your desired behavior.

Comment: by using  `e.preventDefault();` you have permanently disabled any action on the radio buttons

Answer (score 0):

addEventListener can help you

```js
function disableClick(e) {
    e.target.checked = false; // clear current radio button
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
}
document.getElementById("fmale").addEventListener("click",disableClick)
document.getElementById("male").addEventListener("click",disableClick)
```

```html
<input id="fmale" type="radio" name="gender" value="1" checked="checked" />
<input id="male" type="radio" name="gender" value="2">
```

Comment: This makes OP's original code cleaner, but doesn't change the functionality or resolve the issue.

Comment: add "e.target.checked" for clear current radio button

Answer (score 0):

'e.preventDefault()' and 'return false' are preventing next radio button to getting checked.

Comment: This doesn't resolve OP's issue, this is just a comment.

Comment: @AnonymousSB not clear what he is trying to achieve. Also, I can't add a comment.

Answer (score 0):

`e.preventDefault` does not prevent the radio button's attribute `checked` from being set to `true`. You can `console.log(e.target.checked)` to see it's set `true`, even though `e.preventDefault()` prevents it from visually showing as checked.

The below demo allows the other radio button to automatically be set to `checked = false`, but then sets the currently clicked on radio to `false` as well.

I'm not sure why you want to do this, but here you go

#### Solution

```js
$('#fmale').click(function(e) {
  e.target.checked = false;
});

$('#male').click(function(e) {
  e.target.checked = false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="fmale" type="radio" name="gender" value="1" checked="checked">
<input id="male" type="radio" name="gender" value="2">
```

Comment: It does the same for me, like the code I sent, erases my first choice, and the second choice - does not do

Comment: @rikush I don't understand what you want. You want to deselect all radio buttons when you select the deselected radio button? Or something else? What does "and the second choice - does not do" mean?